# padding the text of a HTML input field

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML input field.

If I do

> padding-left: 10px

, it will move the text of the input field to the left BUT, the right side of the input field (or right side of the box) disappears - (please see the attachment).

What CSS setting can I use to fix this?

TIA[image]

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML & CSS relating to this question

Comment: Provide your html, css code here

Comment: There must be a problem with the container too. Could you provide more  code?

Comment: Hello - code for input field is below:<div class="wmeditor-readonlyNode" role="textbox" aria-labelledby="main_pageContainerButtonActions_pageSettings_pageContainer3_pageSettingsCompany_addressEditor1" style="border-width: 1px; left: 122px; top: 2px; width: 187px; height: 24px; line-height: 26px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; word-wrap: normal;"> 999 Sesame Street</div>

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS file

```
input {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use box sizing property. Always use this in your reset.css :

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below css:

```
input {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Also provide width to your input field